# Enter each element of an array as a record of each mysql column

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

What I want is to enter each element of an array in a field of my database this is my structure example table record has four fields value1, value2 value3, value4 I want to enter the following records that are generated from the following code

```
arraynew = array("5878-1","8978-12","2523-1");
$dato1 = "00320555555";
$dato2 = "22/02/2018";
$dato3 = "Maria Mercedes del Barrio";
$dato4 = $arraynew;

$data = array($dato1,$dato2,$dato3,$dato4);

$nuevo = array();
for($i= 0; $i < count($dato4); $i++ ){
    array_push($nuevo, array(
        $data[0],
        $data[1],
        $data[2],
        $data[3][$i]
    ));
}
echo print_r($nuevo);
echo var_dump($nuevo);
```

this is the structure of the array

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 5878-1 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 8978-12 ) [2] => Array ( [0] => 00320555555 [1] => 22/02/2018 [2] => Maria Mercedes del Barrio [3] => 2523-1 ) ) 1
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '5878-1' (length=6)
  1 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '8978-12' (length=7)
  2 => 
    array (size=4)
      0 => string '00320555555' (length=11)
      1 => string '22/02/2018' (length=10)
      2 => string 'Maria Mercedes del Barrio' (length=25)
      3 => string '2523-1' (length=6)
```

what I need is to enter each array enter it in a row with its corresponding field

Comment: a simple insert query? at least make an attempt

Comment: my head hurts bad.

Comment: [https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp)

Comment: Is the input data coming from user input? or is this trusted/secure data?

Comment: Hello, I already tried what I did was create a for each annulated and in the middle of the last one for each to establish the sql sentence and the only thing that I entered is the last value of the array and what I need this all these data I get from a form but the last field that is not repeated is obtained from a dynamic input that the user enters since they are N different enrollments

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that you are processing user-supplied data and so a mysqli prepared statement is called for.  My method will make 3 calls to the database and keep a tally of how many affected rows resulted from the queries.

(I have tested this code to be successful on my server.)

Code:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(...$fourIndexedCredentials);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO tablename (value1, value2, value3, value4) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $dato1, $dato2, $dato3, $dato4);

$dato1 = "00320555555";
$dato2 = "22/02/2018";
$dato3 = "Maria Mercedes del Barrio";
$arraynew = ["5878-1", "8978-12", "2523-1"];
$tally = 0;
foreach ($arraynew as $dato4) {  // the declaration of $dato4 is all that is required for binding
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        ++$tally;
    }
}
echo $tally;  // output: 3
```

Comment: Thank you I will try to put it to work today I am analyzing to establish the changes, Thank you very much mickmackusa

Comment: If you have questions about the php or the db table structure, just ask me.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wJnJyqTQ81AAGfU4OdD_y-V5fuPtpV0Q/view?usp=sharing this is my database structure help me please

Comment: The Estructura view is more important to me.  The id column needs to be the Primary key and it should auto-increment.  I don't know you skill level, where are you stuck?

Comment: This is the only project that is in Spanish https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1in9FXcZU2RMZHDixBtaDl6L08WOm6SO1?usp=sharing Thanks for your help

Comment: Hello Mickmackusa, I told you, I gave a twist to my project, developing another simpler logic applied to the work process. I thank you. You have an email to send you a postcard from my country or souvenir. Thank you

Comment: No and you can give me your mail

Comment: I would prefer to handle development support on StackOverflow.   Please explain exactly where you are stuck and I will help you.  Not only do I want to help you, I want this page to help many future readers by providing a clear question and a direct answer.